# Bootstrap 4 Nav Dropdown issue if more than one dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, onclick, hover, bootstrap-4, nav

jsfiddle: http://jsbin.com/wamunoside/1/edit?html,output

```
jsfiddle
```

This is taken from the example given on the Bootstrap 4 docs site: 
just adding a 2nd dropdown to this example below the 1st dropdown found here:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#navbarNavDropdown

So in the jsfiddle this is how you cause the issue:

1.) reduce the width of the output tab so that it shows the menu for mobile (991px or less)

2.) You will see two 'dropdown link', click on the top one which expands the submenu.

3.) click on the other 'dropdown link' below the currently expanded one.

Notice both dropdowns are now closed - should have opened the 2nd dropdown.

Comment: Seems to not be an issue for Bootstrap 4 BETA: http://jsbin.com/wowuwizolo/edit?html,output (original example Bootstrap 4 ALPHA)

Comment: damn there is too many versions of Bootstrap 4... So In my project I am using Bootstrap 4 beta, then there is also bootstrap 4 alpha and also Bootstrap 4 beta 2. This issue still exists in Bootstrap 4 beta, and is 1st fixed in Bootstrap 4 beta 2 -- but that version is not backward compatible with Bootstrap 4 beta and breaks my header completely.

Comment: actually this is fixed for Bootstrap 4 beta, it's just my own code that broke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up issue being my code...
I added the following if `event.type == "mouseleave"` and that seems to have fixed the issue reasonably well, still not perfect (for desktop):

http://jsbin.com/yiyohatequ/edit?html,css,js,output

I'm basically struggling with the best way to get dropdown-menu to appear **'on hover'** for desktop and dropdown to appear **'on click'** for tablet/mobile. so that is why I wrote this code in the 1st place.

```
/* Prevent more than 1 dropdown showing up at once*/
$('.nav-link').hover(function (event) {
//breaks mobile if this fires on "mouseenter". so only fire on "mouseleave"
if (event.type == "mouseleave") {
    var hovered = this.nextElementSibling;//.dropdown-menu
    var navdropdowns = $('.dropdown-menu');
    navdropdowns.each(function (a, b) {
        if (hovered != b) {
            $(b).removeClass('show');
        }
    });
} 
})
```